# Linq code to get the index of an object in an array from an object within a list

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, filtering

Actually, the title is confusing me and I'm not even sure if it's correct. I'm with the following issue here: I have a List where each recipe holds a requiredItem[] array (size 15) This required item array can hold items which are required for the recipe. What I'm tring to do is get all the recipes in a seperate list, that use wood in their recipe as one of the required items.
For example, a recipe could be to need 10 wood to craft a wooden table. This recipe is within the recipe list. A quick google search made me find the following, but I can't figure out how I can access the requiredItem indexes:

```
 List<Recipe> rec = Main.recipe.ToList();
 rec.Select((s, i) => new { i, s })
.Where(t => t.s.requiredItem[indexhere].type == 9)
.Select(t => t.i)
.ToList()
```

I'm sorry I'm not seeing this, I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is really simple.

Also I tried the following. It doesn't bring up any errors, but it's actually not selecting the recipes.

```
        Item refItem = new Item();
        refItem.SetDefaults(ItemID.Wood, false);
        List<int> selectWood = new List<int>(rec.Select((r, i) => new { i, r }).Where(x => x.r.requiredItem.ToList().Contains(refItem)).Select(x => x.i).ToList());
        ErrorLogger.Log(selectWood.ToArray().ToString());
        List<int> indices = new List<int>();
        foreach (var indice in selectWood)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Main.recipe[indice].requiredItem.Length; i++)
            {
                var item = Main.recipe[indice].requiredItem[i];
                if (item.type == ItemID.Wood && item.stack >= 10) indices.Insert(0, indice);
            }
        }

        foreach (var indice in indices)
        {
            ++numberRecipesRemoved;
            rec.RemoveAt(indice);
        }
```

Comment: Setup a data example and show us the example data item(s) to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misreading the question but it is not totally obvious why you need and index (`indexHere`) as an `Any()` clause should suffice.

Without details of the `Recipe` or `requiredItem` it is hard to be sure but the following seems to achieve what you need.

```
enum MaterialType
{
    None,
    Wood,
    Glass,
    Steel,
    Cloth
}

class Ingredient
{

    public Ingredient(MaterialType type, int amount)
    {
        Type = type;
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public MaterialType Type { get; }
    public int Amount { get; }
}

class Recipe
{

    public Recipe(string name, params Ingredient[] ingredients) 
        : this(name, (IEnumerable<Ingredient>) ingredients)
    {          
    }

    public Recipe(string name, IEnumerable<Ingredient> ingredients)
    {
        Name = name;
        Ingredients = ingredients.ToArray();
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public Ingredient[] Ingredients { get; }
}

[TestClass]
public class FindAllItemsFixture
{

    private readonly static IEnumerable<Recipe> AllItemRecipes = new List<Recipe>
    {
        new Recipe("Sword", new Ingredient(MaterialType.Steel, 3)),
        new Recipe("Spear", new Ingredient(MaterialType.Steel, 1), new Ingredient(MaterialType.Wood, 3)),
        new Recipe("Table",  new Ingredient(MaterialType.Wood, 6)),
        new Recipe("Chair",  new Ingredient(MaterialType.Wood, 4)),
        new Recipe("Flag",  new Ingredient(MaterialType.Cloth, 2)),

    };

    IEnumerable<Recipe> GetAllRecipesUsingMaterial(MaterialType materialType)
    {
        return AllItemRecipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Any(i => i.Type == materialType));
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllWoodenRecipes()
    {
        var expectedNames = new string[] { "Spear", "Table", "Chair" };
        var woodenItems = GetAllRecipesUsingMaterial(MaterialType.Wood);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedNames, woodenItems.Select(i => i.Name).ToArray());

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllClothRecipes()
    {
        var expectedNames = new string[] { "Flag" };
        var clothItems = GetAllRecipesUsingMaterial(MaterialType.Cloth);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedNames, clothItems.Select(i => i.Name).ToArray());

    }
}
```

The important piece is the `GetAllRecipesUsingMaterial()` function in the unit test. It selects all the recipes that contain an ingredient of a specified type.

Comment: Woow.. classic example of programming for way too long. This clear example made it so simple. I was able to implement what I want with the following code.
    numberRecipesRemoved += rec.RemoveAll(x => x.requiredItem.Any(i => i.type == ItemID.Wood && i.stack >= 10));
This code is now doing exactly what I want, thank you so much :D (also your GetAllRecipesUsingMaterial example really helps me)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is simple, if I understood your question, you need to show all the recepies that contains wood as required item. So do it like this:

```
var woodRecipes = recipes.Where(r => r.requiredItems.Contains(wood)).ToList();
```